# Running Database in Excel

Tags: database, excel

Is there a way to create a running database in excel (and only in excel, without using third party programs) so for example:
-One worksheet has today's data for each person
-The additional worksheets (one per each person on the first worksheet) keeps a list of each of the past columns
-Each of the worksheets, except for the current worksheet, charts each new row of data added daily.
Here is a picture in case it helps: 
[image: Today's Worksheet]

[image: Member Worksheet]

Comment: This is basically possible, but the key question is: WHY? You're trying to reinvent the wheel, but with significant limitations.

Comment: That's what I asked. I work somewhere where it would be extremely difficult if even possible to get another program approved for installation. I need an easy way to track data from my team.

Comment: Well, this does not remotely qualify as an "easy" way. You would be much better off using something like SQLite. Besides, if you can't install any software, how are you going to get permissions to install and run whatever scripts or macros you intend to use to animate this Frankendatabase?

Comment: Also, why not use Access? It's terrible, yes, but it beats the pants off of Excel as a database platform because that's actually what it's supposed to be. Surely your IT folks are okay with Access?

Comment: Good question, and you'd be surprised. I did just request Access although I'm assuming I won't be able to get it. If i'm correct, and knowing completely that this would obviously not be the best intended use for Excel, how would I do it?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you can run. Can you run VBA macros? Add-ons of any kind? Any kinds of scripts, shell or otherwise? Also, who needs to be able to access it, from how many machines, and what exactly do they need to do? Given the limitations you have described, it may not even be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in Excel, but you need to get the data architecture right.

Use ONE sheet for all raw data. Columns are Date, member, score, number of pages, number of files, notes. New data goes at the bottom of the list. You can use VBA to create a data entry form if you don't want to enter data straight into the sheet. The sheet can be hidden, if needed.

Then use ONE other sheet to create a dynamic report where you can select the time frame and the member to report on. Data is pulled from the raw data sheet and aggregated as required. Pivot tables are immensely powerful.

Using a sheet for each member would be duplication of functionality and bad data design.

Edit: a few conceptual screenshots

The raw data table. New data is added at the bottom of the table. A VBA form can ensure a pleasant user interface, so that the user never sees this table.

[image]

The report could be a pivot table grouped by date. Slicers allow the selection of specific time frames, for example a month. Another slicer allows filtering by a specific member.

[image]

It took me roughly 5 minutes to create the scenario, including making up the dummy data. With a few hours to spend, this could be made really shiny.

Comment: Thank you Teylyn, I'll be honest, I'm a complete newbie when it comes to excel so not sure exactly what some of what you referred to means. Unless i'm not understanding correctly, I have to have a sheet for each member as the list will grow kind of quickly and having different members on one sheet will get crowded fast. I think all I need to do is to be able to push data from one sheet ("Today's sheet") to other sheets by automatically adding a new row in those sheets when a button is pressed on "todays sheet".

Comment: No, you don't need a sheet for each member. You need one report sheet and then select the member whose data you want to see. I added a few screenshots of how that can look.